# Java JTextPane HTML Editor UTF-8 characters encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, html-entities, jtextpane

I'm using JTextPane as simple html editor.

```
jtp=new JTextPane();
jtp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
jtp.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
```

When I call jtp.getText() I get nice html code with all special chars escaped. But I don't want escape national characters (polish) but only special html chars like &, <, >
When I enter in editor

```
<foo>ą ś &
```

I get

```
&lt;foo&gt;&#261; &#347; &amp;
```

but I would like get

```
&lt;foo&gt;ą ś &amp;
```

How it is possile?

Comment: I use `charset=cp1251` instead of `charset=UTF-8`

Comment: hmmm are you take these data from File or from WWW ???, because then you have to encode Buffer with proper Charset to the String value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible, unfortunately.

There's a flaw inside [javax.swing.text.html.HTMLWriter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLWriter.java) -- it is hardcoded to convert any symbol that is not ASCII to its numeric representation:

```
default:
    if (chars[counter] < ' ' || chars[counter] > 127) {
        if (counter > last) {
            super.output(chars, last, counter - last);
        }
        last = counter + 1;
        // If the character is outside of ascii, write the
        // numeric value.
        output("&#");
        output(String.valueOf((int)chars[counter]));
        output(";");
    }
    break;
}
```

This logic cannot be controlled in any way.

**BUT** If you **really really** need that functionality you could do the **crazy stuff**:

1. copy and paste [HTMLWriter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLWriter.java) sources into `HTMLWriterHack` (in the same package `javax.swing.text.html` and renaming all strings inside)
2. Replace the above listed three `output` lines with something like `output(String.valueOf(chars[counter]));`
3. copy and paste [HTMLDocument](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.java) sources into `HTMLDocumentHack` (in the same package `javax.swing.text.html`, renaming all strings inside, making it extend `HTMLDocument` and removing clashing methods)
4. Use the CustomEditorKit listed below instead of HTMLEditorKit

---

```
class CustomEditorKit extends HTMLEditorKit {
    @Override
    public void write(Writer out, Document doc, int pos, int len) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
        HTMLWriterHack writer = new HTMLWriterHack(out, (HTMLDocumentHack) doc);
        writer.write();
    }
    @Override
    public Document createDefaultDocument() {
        StyleSheet styles = getStyleSheet();
        StyleSheet ss = new StyleSheet();
        ss.addStyleSheet(styles);
        HTMLDocumentHack doc = new HTMLDocumentHack(ss);
        doc.setParser(getParser());
        doc.setAsynchronousLoadPriority(4);
        doc.setTokenThreshold(100);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

---

Although the steps above work (I tested it), I certainly wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: Bro where do I supposed to find the `HTMLDocumentHack`?

Comment: Bro, you solved my problem too, thank you so much, I have been stuck for 2 weeks, thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, all characters above code 127 are translated to a numeric entity **& # number ;**. The HTML-entities are translated into named entities **& lt ;** , and so on. So you may easily resubstitute them. *(This is done in HTMLWriter.output, and there seems to be no provision for character sets whatsoever.)*

Comment: So I can't distinguish html-entities from non html-entities? So far I came with pattern (&#[0-9]+;) and then StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4($1). It's seems working

Comment: You did right, I meant that by your parsing you leave ", < and > untouched, as they are *named* entities like & quot ; .